# SUPSTRONICS X400 Raspberry pi 3 with Android things

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, android-things

I've been trying to create a car head using the raspberry pi and android things. In order to power the car audio I bought this amp [Suptronics X400](http://www.suptronics.com/xseries/x400.html) but I haven't been able to use it as the default output for audio and I'm trying to integrate the Spotify SDK. I tried to create the drive but most of the [Documentation here](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/drivers/audio.html) has been removed from the libraries. I'm a bit lost

Answer (score 0):

The audio driver user driver is no longer available in Android Things. The right way is to use the `AudioTrack` class and set the preferred device type, as is done in [this sample project](https://github.com/androidthings/sample-googleassistant).

You may need to specify the audio bus you want to send sounds to:

```
private AudioDeviceInfo findAudioDevice(int deviceFlag, int deviceType) {
    AudioManager manager = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    AudioDeviceInfo[] adis = manager.getDevices(deviceFlag);
    for (AudioDeviceInfo adi : adis) {
        if (adi.getType() == deviceType) {
            return adi;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then find the I2S bus:

```
mAudioInputDevice = findAudioDevice(AudioManager.GET_DEVICES_INPUTS, AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_BUS);
mAudioOutputDevice = findAudioDevice(AudioManager.GET_DEVICES_OUTPUTS, AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_BUS);
```

Then you can run `audioTrack.setPreferredDevice(mAudioOutputDevice);`

Comment: I tried that as well but mAudioOutputDevice is returned as null

Comment: Which developer preview of Android Things are you using? I don't know why it'd be returning `null`.

Comment: I'm using the lasted one (preview 7). Is there any way to test if the pins are working properly? I do think the device works well because it's powering the raspberry pi but could it be any connection issue? Also should I add any module load in the boot file?

Comment: You can put a logic analyser on the i2s bus, but even if the device isn't connected I'm unsure why you couldn't find that audio bus.

Comment: I reinstalled everything and now the SDK it's returning a device (it's not null anymore) using the findAudioDevice method but still does nothing :/ I don't see anything from the device documentation if I have to activate any GPIO first or something which for what I can see is what the driver for the voicehat does

Comment: This may be entirely dependent on the specifics of your amp, but it should at least resolve your i2s issues (i2s may come from your Pi, but it may not be processed completely through your peripheral). If you have a logic analyzer, you can put it on a few different pins to see if you are getting i2s data and use it to debug the communication line. The VoiceHat uses GPIO to switch between mics and speaker -- others like the ReSpeaker 2-mic hat use I2C to send commands.